# What algorithm should I use for encrypting and embedding a password for an application?

Tags: passwords, encryption

What algorithm should I use for encrypting and embedding a password for an application?

It obviously is not bullet proof, but it should be good enough to thwart someone scanning the database with a hex editor, or make it hard for someone who has the skills to use a debugger to trace the code to work out, either by scanning for the encrypted password, or using a debugger to run through the decryption code.

Object Pascal would be nice.

**Major Edit**

I think I did not explain myself well enough. The password needs to be decrypted back into its original form and applied. The application itself uses a local SQL database and a local webserver, and the password is fixed and can't be changed by the end users. It is to ensure that changes to be made only from within the app itself. The user passwords are only to allow access to the app itself, rather than the database

/vfclists

Answer (score 1):

If you want an easy solution just stick with a good hashing algorithm like **MD5** and store just the hash inside your application. Then whenever the user inserts the password you will calculate the hash of the password and check if it's equal to the one stored.

Of course this approach is a simple solution that doesn't allow you to retrieve the password if it's lost but it should work quite fine if you just need some protection..

EDIT: I mentioned MD5 that *was* fair good but not anymore, of course you can choose any other stronger function like **SHA-2** (512/384) that is more robust. I just wanted to explain an approach more than using a specific hashing algorithm.

Comment: MD5 is not a good hashing algorithm any more - Xiaoyun Wang's attacks in 2005 have left it pretty well discredited.

Comment: Everything depends on what kind of security you want to prove. Of course having a salt is __necessary__ when we're talking about accounts of a website. But for a casual application that only needs to store the password is an encrypted way this will just move the problem in where to store the salt separately to effectively have some benefits. :)

Answer (score 0):

SHA should be ok for you, best with salt.

I don't know Object Pascal very well, but probably this will help you:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/op-crypt/

Answer (score 0):

When an application has to do password checking only, it is best to save a hash. An hash can not be decrypted, but it can be checked whether the password the user enters has the same hash.

If you want to save the password so that it can be recovered, it is best to encrypt it first, using some crypto library.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest SHA1, its one way encryption, i've used it before and by far no one has decrypted it!
If you need more information on sha1 visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm and http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/sha.html.

PS: If you're using php you can simply encrypt with SHA1 using the sha1(); function!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you're aiming for is not storing passwords *in* the application, but trying to prevent the application *itself* from being run without the password, as a form of DRM. If that's the case, and you're looking to stymie people with debuggers, I think you're well into the realm of needing either a hardware dongle, or a network-based lock. Off the top of my head, I know SafeNet carry products that do this (and I've had some exposure to them in the past, they seem decent), but I don't know how well they compare to the rest of the market.

Answer (score 0):

If you want as much real security as is possible in the scenario you're describing, you should require that when the system is installed an "administrator" enters the database password and his own administrator password; the application should then store a salted hash of the administrator's password, and it should store the database password encrypted with a differently-salted hash of the administrator's password.  The database password (or information sufficient to reconstruct it) will be kept in memory while the program is running, but absent the administrator password there would be no way to retrieve when the program isn't running, even with full knowledge of the system.

If it's necessary to allow multiple users to access the database, an "add user" button could allow the addition of a user account.  When the user types his password, use it to store hashed/encrypted data as with the administrator.

Any user with a debugger would be able to leverage his knowledge of a valid user account and password into knowledge of the database password, but someone who didn't have knowledge of a valid account password wouldn't be able to do anything.

Answer (score -1):

If I am interpreting your question right, then you want to basically distribute your application to users, allow them to run it, and have the application update your database.  At the same time, you want to prevent that person from being able to log in to the database and use it themselves directly.

If your program can be decompiled (like java, but I don't know about other languages like C, C++), then the person who has your application will be able to see the source code.  Once they have that, there will most certainly be some way they can discover the user name and password.  Even if your source code has stored the password using a reversible encryption algorithm, the person who holds your source code will be able to write similar code as yours to reverse the encryption and discover the password.

Even if your application cannot be decompiled, the user may be able to capture the network packets it sends to the database and determine the password from that.  I don't know if you can communicate with the database over SSL.

Instead, I believe you need to split your application into client and server applications.  You can write a restful web application, or use a messaging service (like JMS for example), and write a client application that uses it.

In that case, you may or may not want to have user accounts that are managed by your server side application.  Let me be clear here, I am not talking about database accounts, but accounts that your application manages, and whose details happen to be stored in the database.  If you do create user accounts, you can follow the pattern in my original answer shown below.

============== Hashing Approach, my original answer ============

As others have already mentioned, it's best to add salt to the password and use a digest algorithm before you store the password in your database.  However, I think a little more detail is in order.

Using SHA1 or SHA2 with a salt value may be pretty strong, but there are even stronger methods.  I highly recommend that you [read this section of the spring security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-password-encoding) manual.  I don't think you are using spring or java, but that section covers the concepts involved very well.  Allow me to paraphrase:

1. Use at least an 8 byte salt value, up to 16 bytes would be great.  The salt value should be different for every account, if it is the same then a cracker will only need to produce one rainbow table!  It should be randomly generated.  The documentation doesn't say this, but I also recommend using a secure random number generator, don't use a random number seed that produces a consistent sequence of numbers.
2. You should hash the password multiple times because it will cause brute force password hacking attempts to take increasingly more time.  Indeed, you may want a slow password encoding algorithm instead of a fast one.
3. Store the raw salt value in the database along with the password, you can even store it in the same field/column.  This is required so passwords can be verified in the future.

The [BCryptPasswordEncoder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html) is a good example of this.

===============

One alternative approach that may or may not solve your problem is to create a database account that has limited privileges.  For example, you could create a database account that can only select, update, insert, and delete on specific tables in your database.  You may not find this acceptable, because you may not want to let people do those operations directly, while you may want to let the application do those operations.  It depends on your specific situation.

Comment: Most of the other answers were made before the question was edited to clarify. The question is asking how to store the password for the database inside the application in a way that allows the application to access the database without allowing the user direct access to the database. You can't use a hashed version of the database password to login to the database.

Comment: @Quentin, I think the author was confused about the best approach for how to solve this problem, I also think his question is phrased confusingly, even with the edits.  If what he really wants to do is distribute his code to peers, let them run the application, and have that control the database, there is always going to be some way they could discover the password.  He would have to add some kind of service in between the application that users run, and his database, and in that case he would have to create user accounts using the pattern in my answer.

Comment: @Quentin, if you agree with my revisions then please up-vote it or undo the down vote.